# What is the differences between RetrieveRequest and IOrganizationService.Retrieve in CRM?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm new in CRM workflow step development by C#. I need to know what is the main difference between `RetrieveRequest`  and `Retrieve` in `IOrganizationService`.
When must use which one?
And is there any example to show how use this objects to run in a performer manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the `Retrieve` method suffices.

The `RetrieveRequest` however adds an interesting feature: it provides the option to query data associated with the retrieved object in one go.

Imagine you need invoice data along with its Invoice Product records. One option would be to create a `QueryExpression` and join the results of the invoice entity and the invoicedetail entity. This would result in one, potentially large table.

With the `RetrieveRequest` you can query records associated with the retrieved entity in one request.

An example:

```
private readonly IOrganizationService _service;

public Entity GetFullInvoice(Guid invoiceId)
{
    var request = new RetrieveRequest
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(allColumns: true),
        Target = new EntityReference("invoice", invoiceId),
        RelatedEntitiesQuery = new RelationshipQueryCollection()
    };

    var relation = new Relationship("invoice_details");
    relation.PrimaryEntityRole = EntityRole.Referenced;

    var invoiceDetailQuery = new QueryExpression("invoicedetail");
    invoiceDetailQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(allColumns: true);
    invoiceDetailQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("invoiceid", ConditionOperator.Equal, invoiceId);

    var result = (RetrieveResponse)_service.Execute(request);

    return result.Entity;
}
```

The `Entity` object returned by `GetFullInvoice` has a `RelatedEntities` property holding the entity collections related to the invoice.

Multiple queries can be added to the `RetrieveRequest`, so it would also be possible to retrieve associated activities etc. in one go as well.

Comment: Thank for your clear answer. Is any test has been done to check the performance? I have some related Entities. Is it better to Retrieve base entities and there related by RetreiveMultipleRequest or by organizationService.Retrive base and then fetch related in a loop?

Comment: I guess it depends on the data you have to query. A `QueryExpression` is translated into a single SQL (JOIN) SELECT. The `RetrieveRequest` is translated into a SELECT for the main entity record and a separate SELECT for every related entities query added to the request. When you expect to receive many related records, a single `QueryExpression` can result in a large result set, due to the fact that the columns of the main entity record are duplicated in every single row. A `RetrieveRequest` can deliver a more compact data set and save a round-trip to the application server.

Comment: Thanks again. When I run my custom workflow on a single record, it is fine, when choose multiple records and run again, waiting status comes for my processes. I think it is because of my code and must tune up queries or using multi-threading concept. Is it any way to prevent overwriting runs of workflow, when we run it on multiple records? How can I handle multiple and concurrent runs of a workflow with multiple records?

Comment: Basically, you can't. There are scenarios you need to design one consistent batch process. Having lots of concurrent executing workflow instances can often lead to problems: the system slowing down, dead locks etc.

Comment: I have a workflow step for my custom entity. In my code, I retrieve multiple entities and update some entity else. What is the best practice for writing my code to be able working with multiple and concurrent runs in CRM? Is any example exists? ( in C# language).

Comment: In most cases your approach should just work fine. It's the number of concurrent runs that should be taken into account. A stress test can give give you an idea of the scalability of your solution.

Comment: I need step by step and best practice examples in C# language about complex workflow steps. Where can I find it?

Comment: I doubt you will find examples that prove to be useful for you. At this point it comes to experience and eventually trying out a few options.

Answer (score 0):

A `RetrieveRequest` and the `Retrieve` method of `IOrganizationService` do exactly the same thing: retrieve a specific record.

Eventually `RetrieveRequest` can be batched (using the `ExecuteMultipleRequest` message) but personally I never see a `RetrieveRequest` batched, because normally `UpdateRequest` or `DeleteRequest` are the one batched in order to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are they really equal in performance? My workflow step, have multiple retrieve and update with complex filter expression. When I run on multiple entities, it goes to waiting state! Thus, I need the most performant way.