# get related data from ms dynamics crm using XRM SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamics-crm, kentico

I'm trying to retrieve data from crm in a .net application, using the SDK.
I've managed to do simple queries to retrieve lists, but I would now like to get the related entities with items, rather than the ids.

I have tried things like

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
  {
    EntityName = "opportunity",
....

LinkEntity linkEntityAccount = new LinkEntity()
 {
    LinkFromEntityName = "opportunity",
    LinkFromAttributeName = "opportunityid",
    LinkToEntityName = "serviceappointment",
    LinkToAttributeName = "regardingobjectid",
    JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
    Columns = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "scheduledstart", "scheduledend" }),
    EntityAlias = "service"
 };

query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntityAccount);
```

(This will return a collection of entities from the opportunity table)

However the LinkedEntities just put the two columns in the returns entities.

What i would like is (say for this example) is a `entity.serviceappointment` to be the the entity containing the service appointment entity/data. Instead of in entity there being fields such as `service.scheduledstart` and `service.scheduledend`

I have looked at the `Relationship` and `RelationshipQueryCollection` things in the SDK but i have been unable to setup a query that will do the query, without first getting the `opportunity` entities. But it looks like that maybe what I need? I'm not sure.

Is this even possible? Or should I just continue to query entities individually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `QueryExpression` the `LinkEntity` represents a join. That's why the fields of the joined table are in the `Entity` row. They can be distinguished from the 'real' entity attributes by the fact that their names are prefixed (including a dot) and their values are wrapped in an `AliasedValue` object.

It is possible to unwrap them and create strong typed `Entity` objects, but you will need to write the code yourself.

Alternatively you can consider a few other options:

1. Query for `serviceappointment` records and join the `opportunity` records.
2. Retrieve `opportunity` records one by one using the `RetrieveRequest` and include the query for the related service appointments in the request. (See also this discussion on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327565/what-is-the-differences-between-retrieverequest-and-iorganizationservice-retriev).)
3. Create an Action returning all data you need in a convenient `OrganizationResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to get the entire linked entity data (as an `Entity` object) that I know of (that's not to say it's impossible, mind you).

But I think it'd be a lot easier to just query the data you need in another request.

- Find the list of opportunities you need
- Use the regarding object IDs as the parameter of an "IN" filter for the second query.